# Do I need desktopcouch-se?

Tags: desktopcouch

Do I need desktopcouch-se service? It seems that it is eating my thinkpad computing resources. Please see below that powertop confirms this. "Ubuntu with no-effects" is running on my thinkpad. Please also take a look at the output of powertop and let me know if there are any unnecessary services are running.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Desktopcouch is part of Ubuntu One. If you want to stop that uncheck it in `startup applications`. And the problem you have is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/desktopcouch/+bug/578219) so please login/register at launchpad and add yourself to the 'Does this bug affect you?'. That way it'll get more attention!

[image]

Turning it off will probably also take care of `ubuntuone-syncd`